# How can I get previous and next links in Magento blog post pages?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

On Magento 1.9.1, I have a blog post template that has the following:

```
<?php $post = $this->getPost(); ?>
<?php $next = Mage::getModel('blog/post')->load($post->getId()+1); ?>
<?php $prev = Mage::getModel('blog/post')->load($post->getId()-1); ?>
```

and the at the bottom of the template there are links for the next and previous article:

```
<a href="/blog/<?php echo $prev->getIdentifier(); ?>" class="prev">< Previous</a>
<a href="/blog/<?php echo $next->getIdentifier(); ?>" class="next">Next ></a>
```

This works fine but with one problem;  it doesn't take into account if the article is enabled or disabled.

Is there a way for it to exclude 'disabled' articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with following code with some modifications like replace 'id' with primary key field for post table and same for 'status' field with status column name.

```
<?php $post = $this->getPost(); ?>  
<?php  
    $prevCollection = Mage::getModel('blog/post')->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToFilter('id', array('lt' => $post->getId()))
          ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'enabled')
          ->addOrder('id','DESC');
    $prevCollection->getSelect()->limit(1);
    if($prevCollection->count()){
      $prev = $prevCollection->getFirstItem();
    }

    $nextCollection = Mage::getModel('blog/post')->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('id', array('gt' => $post->getId()))
         ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'enabled');
    $nextCollection->getSelect()->limit(1);
    if($nextCollection->count()){
      $next = $nextCollection->getFirstItem();
    }
  ?>
```

and replace your html code with

```
    <?php if(isset($prev) && $prev->getId()):?>
          <a href="/blog/<?php echo $prev->getIdentifier(); ?>" class="prev">< Previous</a>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if(isset($next) && $next->getId()):?>
          <a href="/blog/<?php echo $next->getIdentifier(); ?>" class="next">Next ></a>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Hope this will help you.